# what add-on for eclipse would make it act as dreamweaver or filezilla like ftp?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ftp, dreamweaver, filezilla

One of the things that more upsets me from eclipse is the non "obvious" treat to ftp.
Its ok for me to import an ftp plugin , for me this should be "by default" but at my version Version: 4.2.1 Build id: M20120914-1800 , I see no ftp to connect to my remote filesystem, i must say that i created my project localy from a zip , unzipped at my workspace folder, then i created the project giving it the name of the folder that was dezipped, now and that is the sad part , i have to use filezilla to upload all my changes as i was not able to figure out how to set up an filezilla like ftp pluging from an existing workspace to a remote server .

I will miss from dreamweaver (no funny comments please) the ability to promt you with a message just in case the importing file (the one going from my PC) is different from that in the server-side, not just in size but also in date, but will not prompt in case you downloaded  with the ftp itself(the one i am dreaming to find) so i could choose whether to overwrite or not ...

Could someone PLEASE point out a tutorial ,a pluging or create one(believe me you will be soon rich) to behave like, as i didnt found any that acts likely a filezilla or dreamweaver ftp  for Eclipse ?

I cannot imagine how many thousands of novel programmers are stuck onto dreamweaver ( no offence) becouse of this fact....